# Entity framework transaction error after deleting a row and inserting a new row with same primary key

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 in Visual Studio 2008. I believe the SQL Server is 2005. I am using Entity Framework to access the database.

I've got the following table with a composite primary key based upon `iRequest` and `sCode`:

```
RequestbyCount
    iRequest  integer
    sCode     varchar(10)
    iCount    integer
```

`iRequest` is a foreign key to a list of requests.

When a request is updated, I want to clear out the existing `RequestbyCounts` for that request and then add in the new `RequestbyCounts`. More than likely, the only difference between the old rows will be the Count.

For my code, I attempt it as follows:

```
//delete ALL our old requests
var oldEquipList = (from eq in myDB.dbEquipmentRequestedbyCountSet
                    where eq.iRequestID == oldData.iRequestID
                    select eq).ToList();
foreach (var oldEquip in oldEquipList)
{
     myDB.DeleteObject(oldEquip);
}

//  myDB.SaveChanges();    <---- adding this line makes it work

//add in our new requests
foreach (var equip in newData.RequestList)   //newData.RequestList is a List object
{
   if (equip.iCount > 0)
   {
    //add in our actual request items
      RequestbyCount reqEquip = new RequestbyCount();
      reqEquip.sCodePrefix = equip.sCodePrefix;
      reqEquip.UserRequest = newRequest;
      reqEquip.iCount = equip.iCount;
      myDB.AddToRequestbyCount(reqEquip);
   }
}

myDB.SaveChanges();   //save our results
```

The issue is when I run it with the intermediate `SaveChanges` line uncommented, it works as desired. But my understanding is that doing this breaks the transaction apart.

If I leave the intermediate SaveChanges commented out as above, the process fails and I receive a

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_RequestbyCount'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.RequestbyCount'.\r\nThe statement
>   has been terminated.

Obviously, without doing the intermediate `SaveChanges`, the old rows are NOT removed as desired.

I do NOT want the results saved unless everything succeeds.

I would rather not take the following approach:

```
//add in our new requests
foreach (var equip in newData.RequestList)
{
   if (equip.iCount > 0) && (**it isn't in the database**)
   {
    //add in our actual request items
      RequestbyCount reqEquip = new RequestbyCount();
      reqEquip.sCodePrefix = equip.sCodePrefix;
      reqEquip.UserRequest = newRequest;
      reqEquip.iCount = equip.iCount;
      myDB.AddToRequestbyCount(reqEquip);
   } else if (**it is in the database**) && (equip.iCount == 0) {
      **remove from database**
   } else {
      **edit the value in the database**
   }
}
```

Am I stuck doing the above code that basically makes a bunch of little calls to the database to check if an item exists?

Or is there some method that tell the framework to attempt to delete the rows I want but rollback if there is a failure inserting the new rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be using transactions at all. You need to wrap all your code in

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    ...
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Even better

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    { 
       your code 
       transaction.Complete();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
       // handle error
    }
}
```

Using the try/catch block will ensure that the transaction is not committed if an exception occurs, which is what you stated you wanted.

Lot's more on entity framework transactions at [Microsoft's web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). The explanations there are quite good.

Comment: True... I am not explicitly using a transaction.  But I am still at a loss on the Entity Framework's behavior in this case.  By all appearances, it is doing NO order to the statements I've provided.  It SHOULD be doing them in the order presented and thus there should NOT be any data to cause a primary key failure.

Comment: @John Stone I think I understand. You think EF would queue your changes, then apply them in order when you call SaveChanges(), which is how a transaction works. I don't know the inner workings of EF well enough to be sure, but I suspect it doesn't work that way because EF can only manage one state of an object. In other words, if you are adding an object with an id of 1, the EntityState is marked as Added - If you had just marked that same object (same Id) for deletion (i.e. DeleteObject()), it gets changed back to Added

Comment: cont .. with the new properties you set. When you call SaveChanges() the first state is lost. EF tries to insert the row, but it was never actually deleted. Doing the deleting and adding within a TransactionScope, and calling SaveChanges after the delete) will address your concern of all or nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick run down.  I think this is what I am looking for to solve my issue.